# How to generate a specific synthetic image

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, colors, fft

I want to generate a black 64x64 pixels image with a 5x10 pixels white rectangle in the center and then, use the 2D Fourier Transform to plot the original imagen, module, phase and recovered image.

This is my code:

```
image_1_black = double(zeros(64, 64, 3, 'uint8'));
image_1_white = double(ones(5, 10, 3, 'uint8'));

% I need to do something like this:
% image1 = image_1_black with image_1_white

IMAGE_1 = fft2(image_1);
IMAGE_1 = fftshift(IMAGE_1);

IMAGE_1_REC = fftshift(IMAGE_1);
image_1_rec = ifft2(IMAGE_1_REC);

figure;
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imagesc(image_1);
colormap(gray); 
axis off;
title('Original image');

subplot(2, 2, 2);
imagesc(100*log(1 + abs(IMAGE_1)));
colormap(gray);
axis off;
title('Magnitude spectrum');

subplot(2, 2, 3);
imagesc(angle(IMAGE_1));
colormap(gray);
axis off;
title('Phase spectrum');

subplot(2, 2, 4);
imagesc(image_1_rec);
colormap(gray);
axis off;
title('Imagen recuperada');
```

I know how to generate both images individually, but don't know how to combine them to get the desired image with my code working properly.

Thank you all!

Comment: Do you want the white image on top of the first image? or a second one?

Comment: I need the white image in the center of the first image

Comment: Why are you creating a secondary white image then?

Comment: Just do:

image_1_black = double(zeros(64, 64, 3, 'uint8'));
image_1_black(29:34,24:39,:) = 1;

this should do it

Comment: @user2205242 Just do `image_1_black = zeros(64,64,3);`.  Specifying `uint8` as the type then casting to `double` is superfluous.  It creates a `double` precision matrix by default.

Comment: I've tried before but I get the next error:

    Error using image
    TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0

    Error in imagesc (line 18)
    hh = image(varargin{1},'CDataMapping','scaled');

    Error in Ejercicio1_1 (line 26)
    imagesc(100*log(1 + abs(IMAGE_1)));

Comment: Exactly. But I assumed that he would see that by himself. Otherwise instead of 1, just put 255. :p

Comment: @user2205242 :D oh yes. I didn't know it was the OP who wrote the code.

Comment: No. It's OK. IMAGE_1 is the Fourier 2D Transform of image_1 (which should be the desired image).

Comment: @Kroka Set `image_1 = image_1_black;` then try again.  Make sure you edit the `image_1_black` variable like what user2205242 did to create the square before trying the code.  Also don't scale `imagesc` by 100... it saturates the display.  Let `imagesc` take care of the scaling for you... that's what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
image_1_black = double(zeros(64, 64, 3, 'uint8'));
image_1_black(29:34,24:39,:)=255;
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend you remove the scaling of 100 in the `imagesc` call that the OP has made.  You'll see the spectrum better and it won't saturate the display.  `imagesc` does automatic scaling for you... also, make sure you let the OP know that you set `image_1 = image_1_black;` after the modification to `image_1_black`.

Comment: Ok @rayryeng, thank you.
user2205242 I get the next error doing like you:


Error using image
TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0

Error in imagesc (line 18)
    hh = image(varargin{1},'CDataMapping','scaled');

Error in Ejercicio1_1 (line 18)
imagesc(image_1);

Comment: @Kroka I think you might have a problem with licenses probably. I run your code and it's fine, just as you see in the image.

Comment: @Kroka This code runs fine once you set `image_1 = image_1_black;` and after you put the white square in it.

Comment: @rayryeng I get the same error doing image_1 = image_1_black

Comment: Your error is because you're not running `imagesc` properly... just noticed... please do: `imagesc(log(1 + abs(IMAGE_1)));` please.  You're just doing `imagesc(image_1);` where the data is complex valued. That's why you're getting that error.

Comment: @rayryeng, runnig exactly like you say i get the same error.

Comment: @Kroka No idea. Sorry. Good luck.